Why does $v^{T}xv = vv^{T}x hold?$
I am studying the $QR$ factorization of matrices, by Householder reflections. In the process of deducing the matrix $H_v = I_n -2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}, \quad v \in \mathbb{R}^n$  there is a step that I do not understand and it is the following:
\begin{align}
   y = x -2\frac{v^Txv}{v^Tv} \overbrace{=}^{???} ( I_n -2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv})x
\end{align}
because it uses the equality $v^{T}xv = vv^{T}x$. Why does this equality hold?

$v$ and $x$ are column $n$-vectors. Therefore $v^T$ is a $1\times n$ matrix, $x$ is an $n\times 1$ matrix and $v^Tx$ is a $1\times1$ matrix in the form of $[c]$ for some scalar $c$. If we identify $[c]$ with the scalar $c$, we obtain
$$
\underbrace{v^Tx}_{(1)}\,v=\underbrace{cv}_{(2)}=\underbrace{v[c]}_{(3)}=v\,\underbrace{v^Tx}_{(4)}
$$
where

the $v^Tx$ on the left is treated as the scalar $c$;
$cv$ is the multiplication of $v$ by a scalar $c$;
$v[c]$ is the multiplication of an $n\times1$ matrix $v$ by a $1\times1$ matrix $[c]$, which results in an $n\times 1$ matrix, i.e., a column vector;
the $v^Tx$ on the right is the $1\times1$ matrix $[c]$.


Thank you, the doubts I had are no longer there.

$v^\top x$ is a scalar, so $(v^\top x)v = v(v^\top x)$. We usually write $cv$ when $c$ is a scalar, but it certainly is the same as $vc$.
